# Setting the .src of img elements fails

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2012

i have a 6x6 html-`table`. Each `<td>` holds `<img id="1back" src="" />` where the `id` of each `img`-element is declared as `"1back"` to `"36back"`. Further I have 18 .jpg files named `"1.jpg"` to `"18.jpg"`. Each image has to appear in the grid twice , distributed randomly.

I am trying to accomplish this as follows:

```
    function PopulateGrid() {

        for (var i = 1; i <= 18;i++) //For each image file
        {
            var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (36 - 1 + 1)) + 1; // get random # 1-36


            while (document.getElementById(randomnumber + "back").src != "")
            {
              //if the randomly chosen <img> id is not "" genrate another random number
               randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (36 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
            }

            document.getElementById(randomnumber + "back").src = "Images/" + i + ".jpg";


            //Doing this twice as every image has to appear twice
            while (document.getElementById(randomnumber + "back").src != "") {
                randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (36 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
            }

            document.getElementById(randomnumber + "back").src = "Images/" + i + ".jpg";
        }
    }
```

I am running into wierd behavior in IE, Chrome and FireFox. The script fails in the first while condition. It seems to me like some endless loop. I do not get any error message the page simply never stops loading.

I guess this must be something obvious as usual but I simply can't see the problem here.

Comment: `while (document.getElementById(randomnumber + "back").src != "") {...` I don't see anything in the `while` loop that would set the `.src` to `""`.

Comment: You could try a different approach: Create an array of 36 elements, where each number from 1 to 18 appears twice, `[ 1, 1, 2, 2, ... , 18, 18]`, [shuffle it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array), then assign the image sources in a single loop.

Comment: hi, I agree you may take another approach to implement it. For this piece of code, maybe you can put a console.log() statement inside the while loop to log the random number generated, and see if it takes too long to randomly generated the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with console to see src of your img, when you set src to "" you'll most likely get your base url, so your != "" will never be false. Try setting your img like this:

```
<img id="1back">
```

Then `src != ""` should validate until you assign a src.